# Http requests hanging on new CentOS 7 + apache install. TTFB of 30 secs

Tags: apache-httpd, php7

we've just migrated from CentOS 6.5 with PHP 5.3 to CentOS 7.7 with PHP 7.0 and are getting strange behaviors with some http requests

Most of the time, pages & resources load super fast, and some other time, either the page itself or a XHR request will hang for around 30 secs before it gets done. With all images, css, js etc on the page, we have between 80 to 100 resources per page load.

We compared httpd.conf, php.ini and php.conf of both servers and we can't figure out why it's hanging sometimes, even though we only have one single user F5-ing the page. The problem happens in both http & https. We've also tried setting up MPM Prefork, but it doesn't seem to correlate with the 30 sec delay

As for logs, as soon as the browser performs the call and we see it hanging, we can also find the call in http access logs. In the processes, we can see it's in the "S" state (sleep) for 30 secs, then it disappears... Then the browser also gets the response.

[image: TTFB]
[image: ps]

Here are specs:

- CentOS Linux release 7.7.1908 (Core)
- Server version: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)
- PHP 7.0.33 (cli) (built: Dec 17 2019 16:44:25) ( NTS )
- curl 7.68.0

Loaded apache modules:

```
core_module (static)
so_module (static)
http_module (static)
access_compat_module (shared)
actions_module (shared)
alias_module (shared)
allowmethods_module (shared)
auth_basic_module (shared)
auth_digest_module (shared)
authn_anon_module (shared)
authn_core_module (shared)
authn_dbd_module (shared)
authn_dbm_module (shared)
authn_file_module (shared)
authn_socache_module (shared)
authz_core_module (shared)
authz_dbd_module (shared)
authz_dbm_module (shared)
authz_groupfile_module (shared)
authz_host_module (shared)
authz_owner_module (shared)
authz_user_module (shared)
autoindex_module (shared)
cache_module (shared)
cache_disk_module (shared)
data_module (shared)
dbd_module (shared)
deflate_module (shared)
dir_module (shared)
dumpio_module (shared)
echo_module (shared)
env_module (shared)
expires_module (shared)
ext_filter_module (shared)
filter_module (shared)
headers_module (shared)
include_module (shared)
info_module (shared)
log_config_module (shared)
logio_module (shared)
mime_magic_module (shared)
mime_module (shared)
negotiation_module (shared)
remoteip_module (shared)
reqtimeout_module (shared)
rewrite_module (shared)
setenvif_module (shared)
slotmem_plain_module (shared)
slotmem_shm_module (shared)
socache_dbm_module (shared)
socache_memcache_module (shared)
socache_shmcb_module (shared)
status_module (shared)
substitute_module (shared)
suexec_module (shared)
unique_id_module (shared)
unixd_module (shared)
userdir_module (shared)
version_module (shared)
vhost_alias_module (shared)
dav_module (shared)
dav_fs_module (shared)
dav_lock_module (shared)
lua_module (shared)
mpm_prefork_module (shared)
proxy_module (shared)
lbmethod_bybusyness_module (shared)
lbmethod_byrequests_module (shared)
lbmethod_bytraffic_module (shared)
lbmethod_heartbeat_module (shared)
proxy_ajp_module (shared)
proxy_balancer_module (shared)
proxy_connect_module (shared)
proxy_express_module (shared)
proxy_fcgi_module (shared)
proxy_fdpass_module (shared)
proxy_ftp_module (shared)
proxy_http_module (shared)
proxy_scgi_module (shared)
proxy_wstunnel_module (shared)
ssl_module (shared)
systemd_module (shared)
cgi_module (shared)
php7_module (shared)
mpm_itk_module (shared)
```

http -V output (we can see it's using MPM prefork)

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)
Server built:   Aug  8 2019 11:41:18
Server's Module Magic Number: 20120211:24
Server loaded:  APR 1.4.8, APR-UTIL 1.5.2
Compiled using: APR 1.4.8, APR-UTIL 1.5.2
Architecture:   64-bit
Server MPM:     prefork
  threaded:     no
    forked:     yes (variable process count)
Server compiled with....
 -D APR_HAS_SENDFILE
 -D APR_HAS_MMAP
 -D APR_HAVE_IPV6 (IPv4-mapped addresses enabled)
 -D APR_USE_SYSVSEM_SERIALIZE
 -D APR_USE_PTHREAD_SERIALIZE
 -D SINGLE_LISTEN_UNSERIALIZED_ACCEPT
 -D APR_HAS_OTHER_CHILD
 -D AP_HAVE_RELIABLE_PIPED_LOGS
 -D DYNAMIC_MODULE_LIMIT=256
 -D HTTPD_ROOT="/etc/httpd"
 -D SUEXEC_BIN="/usr/sbin/suexec"
 -D DEFAULT_PIDLOG="/run/httpd/httpd.pid"
 -D DEFAULT_SCOREBOARD="logs/apache_runtime_status"
 -D DEFAULT_ERRORLOG="logs/error_log"
 -D AP_TYPES_CONFIG_FILE="conf/mime.types"
 -D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="conf/httpd.conf"
```

httpd.conf relevant parts - I've removed comments,  and such directives from the listing for clarity, but I can provide more details if needed:

```
Timeout 120
KeepAlive Off
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
KeepAliveTimeout 15
<IfModule prefork.c>
    StartServers       8
    MinSpareServers    5
    MaxSpareServers   20
    ServerLimit      256
    MaxClients       256
    MaxRequestsPerChild  4000
</IfModule>

Listen 80 http
Listen 443 https
NameVirtualHost *:443
SSLStrictSNIVHostCheck off
SSLPassPhraseDialog  builtin
SSLSessionCache         shmcb:/var/cache/mod_ssl/scache(512000)
SSLSessionCacheTimeout  300
Mutex default
SSLRandomSeed startup file:/dev/urandom  256
SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
SSLCryptoDevice builtin

<VirtualHost _default_:443>
    ErrorLog logs/ssl_error_log
    TransferLog logs/ssl_access_log
    LogLevel warn
    SSLEngine on
    SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
    SSLCipherSuite HIGH:3DES:!aNULL:!MD5:!SEED:!IDEA
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/localhost.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/localhost.key
    <Files ~ "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php3?)$">
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </Files>
    <Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </Directory>
    BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-5]" \
             nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
             downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
    CustomLog logs/ssl_request_log \
              "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"
</VirtualHost>

Include conf.modules.d/*.conf
LoadModule mpm_itk_module modules/mod_mpm_itk.so
```

php.ini:

```
allow_url_fopen = On
allow_url_include = Off
auto_append_file =
auto_globals_jit = Off
auto_prepend_file =
bcmath.scale = 0
cli_server.color = On
date.timezone = America/New_York
default_charset = ""
default_mimetype = "text/html"
default_socket_timeout = 60
disable_classes =
disable_functions = shell_exec,system,escapeshellcmd,escapeshellarg,proc_open,popen,parse_ini_file
display_errors = On
display_startup_errors = Off
doc_root =
enable_dl = On
engine = On
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_NOTICE
expose_php = On
file_uploads = On
html_errors = On
ibase.allow_persistent = 1
ibase.dateformat = "%Y-%m-%d"
ibase.max_links = -1
ibase.max_persistent = -1
ibase.timeformat = "%H:%M:%S"
ibase.timestampformat = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
ignore_repeated_errors = Off
ignore_repeated_source = Off
implicit_flush = Off
ldap.max_links = -1
log_errors = On
log_errors_max_len = 1024
mail.add_x_header = On
max_execution_time = 300
max_file_uploads = 50
max_input_time = 60
memory_limit = 128M
mysqli.allow_persistent = On
mysqli.cache_size = 2000
mysqli.default_host =
mysqli.default_port = 3306
mysqli.default_pw =
mysqli.default_socket =
mysqli.default_user =
mysqli.max_links = -1
mysqli.max_persistent = -1
mysqli.reconnect = Off
mysqlnd.collect_memory_statistics = Off
mysqlnd.collect_statistics = On
odbc.allow_persistent = On
odbc.check_persistent = On
odbc.defaultbinmode = 1
odbc.defaultlrl = 4096
odbc.max_links = -1
odbc.max_persistent = -1
output_buffering = 4096
pcre.jit=0
pdo_mysql.cache_size = 2000
pdo_mysql.default_socket=
pgsql.allow_persistent = On
pgsql.auto_reset_persistent = Off
pgsql.ignore_notice = 0
pgsql.log_notice = 0
pgsql.max_links = -1
pgsql.max_persistent = -1
post_max_size = 200M
precision = 14
register_argc_argv = Off
report_memleaks = On
request_order = "GP"
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i
serialize_precision = 17
session.auto_start = 0
session.cache_expire = 180
session.cache_limiter = nocache
session.cookie_domain =
session.cookie_httponly =
session.cookie_lifetime = 0
session.cookie_path = /
session.gc_divisor = 1000
session.gc_maxlifetime = 10800
session.gc_probability = 1
session.hash_bits_per_character = 5
session.hash_function = 0
session.name = PHPSESSID
session.referer_check =
session.save_handler = files
session.save_path = "/home/www/sessions"
session.serialize_handler = php
session.use_cookies = 1
session.use_only_cookies = 1
session.use_strict_mode = 0
session.use_trans_sid = 0
short_open_tag = On
soap.wsdl_cache_dir="/tmp"
soap.wsdl_cache_enabled=1
soap.wsdl_cache_limit = 5
soap.wsdl_cache_ttl=86400
sql.safe_mode = Off
tidy.clean_output = Off
track_errors = Off
unserialize_callback_func =
upload_max_filesize = 200M
url_rewriter.tags = "a=href,area=href,frame=src,input=src,form=fakeentry"
user_dir =
variables_order = "EGPCS"
zend.assertions = -1
zend.enable_gc = On
zlib.output_compression = Off
```

Comment: Those 30 seconds look like a timeout of some sort. Are the filesystems local?

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz

Didn't think about that. Actually yes, the website's document root is on a separate Network File Server.

Here is the output of /proc/mounts:   


`10.34.134.4:/data /home/www nfs rw,noatime,vers=3,rsize=32768,wsize=32768,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,mountaddr=10.34.134.4,mountvers=3,mountport=40072,mountproto=tcp,local_lock=none,addr=10.34.134.4 0 0`

Comment: @mboisvert-bravad were you able to find something about that issue ?

Comment: @Tarek hi, no unfortunately :(